# JQuery addClass not working on anchor tag on click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, singleton

`addClass()` is not working on jQuery on click event. My code looks like this.

```js
init: function () {
      ShareData.config.pageNo = 1;
      ShareData.ajaxCall();
      $(document).on('click', 'ul#pagination li a', function () {
          ShareData.config.pageNo = $(this).text();
          ShareData.ajaxCall();
          $("ul#pagination li a.clickedLink").removeClass("clickedLink");
          $(this).addClass('clickedLink');
      });
  },
  
var pageLink = "";
for (var i = 1; i <= totalPage; i++) {
    if (i == 1) {
        pageLink += "<li><a href='#' class='clickedLink'>" + i + "</a></li>";
    } else {
        pageLink += "<li><a href='#' class=''>" + i + "</a></li>";
    }
}
document.getElementById('pagination').innerHTML = pageLink;
```

```css
.pagination ul li a.clickedLink {
    background-color: #BBB;
}

.pagination ul li a{
    color: #000;
    height: 24px;
    line-height: 24px;
    width: 24px;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    background: #FFF;
    text-shadow: none;
}
.pagination ul li {
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="pagination">
    <ul id="pagination">
    </ul>
</div>
```

And output is like this

[image: html table with pagination]
Everything is working fine on load while, i need to change the background of recently clicked anchor tag.

Comment: #pagination is the id of ul element. :)

Comment: I have a div with class pagination

Comment: Have you inspected the link after the event runs to confirm that the class is not there after the event happens?

Comment: yes I have inspected

Comment: And is it added or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/dk5n4695/2/

```js
$('a').click(function(){
  $('a[class="clickedLink"]').removeClass('clickedLink');
  $(this).addClass('clickedLink');
});
```

```css
.clickedLink {
    background-color: #BBB;
}

ul li a{
    color: #000;
    height: 24px;
    line-height: 24px;
    width: 24px;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    background: #FFF;
    text-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: addClass/siblings/removeClass have existed since v1.0 as per the api.  if it works in v2 it will most likely work in v1 as the only difference between related 1X and 2X versions is IE support.

Comment: @KiranShahi Here you go with the solution https://jsfiddle.net/dk5n4695/2/

Comment: though your is running well here, it is not adding clickedLink class on my a tag. very sad

Comment: @KiranShahi Check the updated jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/dk5n4695/5/

Comment: `$('a[class="clickedLink"]').removeClass('clickedLink');` is working but `$(this).addClass('clickedLink');` is not working.

Comment: Try using https://jsfiddle.net/dk5n4695/6/ .. Instead of click event on anchor tag, I'm using **on** method to attach event to anchor tag as anchor tag is being generated dynamically.  And also add console.log($(this).text());

Answer (score 2):

```js
     $('ul#pagination li a').on('click', function () {
                                $("ul#pagination li a.clickedLink").removeClass("clickedLink");
                                $(this).addClass('clickedLink');
                            });
```

```css
.clickedLink{
color:red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pagination">
    <ul id="pagination">
    <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: @Taplar I updated my code. sorry for the wrong post. but still, I thought it works

Comment: Its not working, When I add `$('ul#pagination li a').addClass('clickedLink');` instead of `$('ul#pagination li a.clickedLink').addClass('clickedLink');` it will change the background of all a tag. I only need to change the background of recently clicked one.

Comment: how you to implement that IDK but try my updated code it works dude.

Answer (score 1):

Try below and see if it works.

```
init: function () {
                ShareData.config.pageNo = 1;
                ShareData.ajaxCall();
                $(document).on('click', 'ul.pagination li a', function () {
                    ShareData.config.pageNo = $(this).text();
                    ShareData.ajaxCall();
                    $("ul.pagination li a.clickedLink").removeClass("clickedLink");
                    $(this).addClass('clickedLink');
                });
            },
```